# Take backup for Gitlab periodically

Tags: gitlab, backup, gitlab-omnibus

By running `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create` we can create backup for Gitlab manually. But is there any way to take Gitlab backup periodically, like daily or monthly.

PS: I want the backup file to be in Local folder not any cloud storage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good start would be the section "[Configuring cron to make daily backups](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_restore.html#configuring-cron-to-make-daily-backups) "

> To schedule a cron job that backs up your repositories and GitLab metadata, use the root user:
>
> ```
> sudo su -
> crontab -e
> ```
>
> There, add the following line to schedule the backup for everyday at 2 AM:
>
> ```
> 0 2 * * * /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create CRON=1
> ```

Comment: It solves for daily backup problem. But, how to backup monthly @VonC

Comment: @DeepakRajana You should be able to configure cron to run once every month: https://crontab.guru/every-month, https://serverfault.com/a/87477/783